# Apache virtual hosts for Drupal and fixed websites

Tags: virtualhost, drupal

I have two websites server1.mydomain.com and server2.mydomain.com.  Server1 is part of a multi host Drupal installation located in dupal-7.2/, Server2 is a static website located in  htdocs/myserver2.

How do I configure Apache to prevent it serving up the drupal site for both hosts?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, you want something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydefaultmultisite.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias server1.mydomain.com
    #ServerAlias ...

    DocumentRoot /var/www/drupal-7.2/
    <Directory /var/www/drupal-7.2>
        AllowOverride All
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server2.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/myserver2
</VirtualHost>
```